# Stream support for git-p4 or good p4 command line tutorial?

Tags: git, command-line-interface, perforce, git-p4

my current project sits in a perforce stream workspace. I am quite familiar with git, but git-p4 does not support streams. Do you know a way around this limitation?

Do you know a good CLI tutorial for perforce (from a git user perspective)? Or even a command line wrapper for perforce to use it similar to git (most likely not possible)?

Thanks,
Lars

Comment: Have you tried `p4 help commands`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that git-p4 supports streams.  You just clone from a depot path, whereas a stream may include several modules.

Here's an article with some notes on how command usage stacks up between Git and Perforce: 
http://answers.perforce.com/articles/KB_Article/Mapping-Git-Terms-and-Commands-to-Perforce/?l=en_US&fs=RelatedArticle

Comment: Thanks for the command line mapping page! That was helpful. Any news on stream support for git fusion?

Comment: On the roadmap, possibly for release after next.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a git-p4 fork with streams support: [git-p4s](http://lm1.github.io/git-p4s)